# How to combine specific value in two array to one array with exception?

Tags: php, arrays

I have following two different array

First array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [course_id] => 21
            [session_id] => 17
            [course_name] => Session 1 Course 1
            [course_description] => Session 1 Course 1
            [course_days] => 2
            [current_rate] => 1000
            [old_rate] => 
            [primary_tutor_id] => 18
            [secondary_tutor_id] => 25
            [additional_time] => 
            [location] => 
            [course_active] => 1

        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [course_id] => 22
            [session_id] => 17
            [course_name] => Session 1 Course 2
            [course_description] => Session 1 Course 2
            [course_days] => 3
            [current_rate] => 1000
            [old_rate] => 
            [primary_tutor_id] => 24
            [secondary_tutor_id] => 25
            [additional_time] => 
            [location] => 
            [course_active] => 1

        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [course_id] => 23
            [session_id] => 17
            [course_name] => Session 1 Course 3
            [course_description] => Session 1 Course 3
            [course_days] => 5
            [current_rate] => 2000
            [old_rate] => 
            [primary_tutor_id] => 26
            [secondary_tutor_id] => 27
            [additional_time] => 
            [location] => 
            [course_active] => 1

        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [course_id] => 26
            [session_id] => 19
            [course_name] => Session 3 Course 2
            [course_description] => Session 3 Course 2
            [course_days] => 2
            [current_rate] => 400
            [old_rate] => 
            [primary_tutor_id] => 29
            [secondary_tutor_id] => 29
            [additional_time] => 
            [location] => 
            [course_active] => 1

        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [course_id] => 27
            [session_id] => 19
            [course_name] => Session 3 Course 3
            [course_description] => Session 3 Course 3
            [course_days] => 1
            [current_rate] => 200
            [old_rate] => 
            [primary_tutor_id] => 26
            [secondary_tutor_id] => 
            [additional_time] => 
            [location] => 
            [course_active] => 1                
        )

)
```

Second Array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [discount_id] => 104
            [session_id] => 17
            [no_course] => 3
            [discount] => 20                
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [discount_id] => 106
            [session_id] => 19
            [no_course] => 2
            [discount] => 20            

        )

)
```

I am trying to combine second array all key and value into first array like following example

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [course_id] => 21
            [session_id] => 17
            [course_name] => Session 1 Course 1
            [course_description] => Session 1 Course 1
            [course_days] => 2
            [current_rate] => 1000
            [old_rate] => 
            [primary_tutor_id] => 18
            [secondary_tutor_id] => 25
            [additional_time] => 
            [location] => 
            [course_active] => 1
            [discount_id] => 104
            [session_id] => 17
            [no_course] => 3
            [discount] => 20

        )
)
```

I have have tried following code and many other code  but i cant get perfect solution. In this two array there is one exception if both [session_id] is same than need array merging other wise as it is array with out merging  :

```
$main=array();
foreach ($courses as $key => $val) {    
            foreach ($session_discount as $se) {
                if ($se->session_id == $val->session_id)
                    $main[$key] = $val;
                array_push($main[$key], $session_discount[0]);
            }
        }
```

Need help..! Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You know the difference between array and object?

Comment: yes i know, any thing wrong i posted sir?

Comment: Yes, `$main[$key]` is object, and you're trying to work with it as with array.

Comment: sorry about that i m confused while coding i had tried to much to convert it but it return empty values

Comment: Instead of `array_push` try something like: `$main[$key]->some_prop = 'Some Value';`

Comment: thank you very much i got the solution by asking your question " difference between array and object?"